# Handlebars - How can I get the key of the current context?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have some data like this:

```
{myData: {"My Key": [1,2], "The Other Key": [3,4]}}
```

I pass the data as a context (in my app I'm doing it as a partial, but `{{with}}` should do the same thing:

```
{{#with myData.[My Key]}}
    hello? {{@key}}  ?
{{/with}}
```

I know this works because if I add `{{#each .}}{{this}}{{/each}}` it prints out `12`.

How do I access "My Key" from within the `{{with}}` block? Putting `{{@key}}` does nothing. Trying `{{../@key}}` causes an error.

edit: this works to look up a single value, but not to iterate over an array like i need

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`
  {{> myPartial key="My Key"}}
`);

Handlebars.registerPartial('myPartial', 'KEY:{{key}}|DATA:{{lookup myData key}}|HARDCODEDATA:{{myData.[My Key]}} ?');

const data = {
  myData: {
    "My Key": 'dog',
    "The Other Key": 'cat'
  }
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to get the `My Key` key? The context within the block is the `value` of `My Key` - ie., `[1, 2]`. The parent context is the `myData` object. There is no `@key` to get unless you use an `#each`. But if you have already hard-coded `My Key` into the template, then it shouldn't be an issue to hard-code it again.

Comment: i just try to avoid places where you have to hardcode a value twice, since you can sometimes forget to update one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to obtain the key in the example you have provided because there is no context that is an iteration of the `myData` object keys. The context within the `#with` block is the value of `myData["My Key"]` and its parent context is `myData`.

However, in your post you state that the `#with` helper should be the same as a partial; but there is a crucial difference. Partials permit you to [pass parameters](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-parameters). Therefor, you could simply pass the key as a parameter when you invoke your partial:

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`
  {{> myPartial myData.[My Key] key="My Key"}}
`);

Handlebars.registerPartial('myPartial', 'hello? {{key}} ?');

const data = {
  myData: {
    "My Key": [1, 2],
    "The Other Key": [3, 4]
  }
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

If you are totally against hard-coding the key twice, you could do something like the following:

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`
  {{> myPartial myData key="My Key"}}
`);

Handlebars.registerPartial('myPartial', 'hello? {{key}} ? {{#each (lookup this key)}}{{this}}{{/each}}');

const data = {
  myData: {
    "My Key": [1, 2],
    "The Other Key": [3, 4]
  }
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could it be done without writing "My Key" twice?

Comment: @stackers: I suppose it could if you didn't pass `myData[My Key]` to the partial.

Comment: okay i figured it out, I can remove passing the data context, then I can get the correct value with {{lookup myData key}}

Comment: but how can i iterate over that?

Comment: @stackers: Yes, you've got it. I have updated my post.

Comment: excellent, that works well enough for me, thanks